# Creating an object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to create an object from the below arrays

```
var v=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

var v1=['A','B','C','D','E']

var result={};
```

key's for the object are (name & target). I want to map the keys with the above two arrays as value like below

```
 {name: "1", target: "A"}
 {name: "2", target: "B"}
 {name: "4", target: "C"}
```

{name: "5", target: "D"}
{name: "6", target: "E"}

I was trying with the below logic

```
v.forEach(key=> result[key]= key);
console.log('ColResult',result);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular or Typescript, just javascript.

Comment: Why `{name: "3", target: "B"}`? Can you specify the requirements? Two arrays are with different lengths, the question could be better if you can **list out complete expected output**.

Comment: SO you want to map a 1-1 array correspondence to a what list of objects it seems -yeah what @YongShun says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first array consists of increasing numbers equal to the index then there is no need for that array at all...

```
result = [];
v1.forEach((v, i) => result.push({ name: i, target: v1[i] }));
```

but in general it should be something like

```
result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
  result.push({ name: v[i], target: v1[i] });
}
```

Comment: function myFunction(a, b) {
   return a.reduce((acc, cur, i) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: b[i] }), {});
}